# how to chose 1 radiobutton from 2 RadioButton Kotlin Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, radio-button

I want to let the user to choose 1 radiobutton only, but whenever i tried to change the choosen button they wont switching to each other instead 2 radiobutton was choosen in the end.

[image]

The result always be like this, they won't switching each other if i press one of them :

[image]

**UPDATES**

```
    private fun pendaftaran( ) {
        val namaForm = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputNama)
        val tglLahirForm = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputTglLahir)
        val getRadioButton = onRadioButtonClicked(?) // what should i throw inside the params? 
        }

fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
           val laki = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButtonLakiDaftar)
            val getLaki = laki.text
            val perempuan = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButtonPerempuanDaftar)
            val getPerempuan = perempuan.text

            if(view is RadioButton) {
                val checked = view.isChecked

                when(view.id) {
                    R.id.radioButtonLakiDaftar ->
                        if(checked) {
                            getLaki.toString()
                        }
                    R.id.radioButtonPerempuanDaftar ->
                        if(checked) {
                            getPerempuan.toString()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to put both the radio buttons under one radio group. If this doesn't work please add the xml.

Comment: @akhilnair do u have the references that i can watch/read about this? thank you

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/37762/android-radiobutton-radiogroup-using-kotlin
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radiogroup-in-kotlin/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-radio-button-in-android-kotlin

Comment: any reason you unaccepted my answer, if you let me know if I can improve it in anyway, it will help me to write better answers in future.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar i just confused if i make a new `fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View)` then how i can call it in other method? let say i have seperate `fun register` how to call `fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View)` to there?

Comment: You are saying if you want to name `onRadioButtonClicked` to something like `register` you can totally do that its up to you you can even name it `xyz`. you just have to add `android:onClick="register"` or `android:onClick="xyz"` in your RadioButton XML instead of `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"`. that is it, its as simple as that.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar no i mean like this... lemme update the post, i'll notify u when it updated

Comment: @Wavesolid Sure let me know

Comment: @dinkar_kumar post has been updated, please kindly to check

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the radio buttons like this in the xml

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ninjas"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)

Comment: as i read from the Docs, it stated "Note: The RadioGroup is a subclass of LinearLayout that has a vertical orientation by default.", can i use RadioGroup in ConstraintLayout?

Comment: yes, you can refer  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radiogroup-in-kotlin/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RadioGroup for that else each radio button will be treated as a separate view(radioButton) and can be controlled separately.

RadioGroup gives this control of choosing one among multiple options.

Example of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio1"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Radio2"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**onRadioButtonClicked** see in both radio button we are calling the same method, so we can control it easily

```
    fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
    if (view is RadioButton) {
        val checked = view.isChecked
        when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.radio1 ->
                if (checked) {
                    // Pirates are the best
                }
            R.id.radio2 ->
                if (checked) {
                    // Radio 2 is selected
                }
        }
    }
}
```